# Как вывести в цикле несколько 'input[type="range"]'?

Tags: javascript

Есть работающий код выводящий три ползунка и три счетчика рядом

Подскажите пожалуйста как все это дело вывести в цикле, потому как если их будет два десятка ползунков кода будет на 1000 строк.

```js
const controller = document.querySelector('.range');
const controller2 = document.querySelector('.range2');
const controller3 = document.querySelector('.range3');
const radialProgress = document.querySelector('.RadialProgress');
const radialProgress2 = document.querySelector('.RadialProgress2');
const radialProgress3 = document.querySelector('.RadialProgress3');
const setProgress = progress => {
  const value = `${progress}%`;
  controller.style.setProperty('--progress', value);
  radialProgress.innerHTML = value;
  radialProgress.setAttribute('aria-valuenow', value);
};
const setProgress2 = progress => {
  const value = `${progress}%`;
  controller2.style.setProperty('--progress2', value);
  radialProgress2.innerHTML = value;
  radialProgress2.setAttribute('aria-valuenow2', value);
};
const setProgress3 = progress => {
  const value = `${progress}%`;
  controller3.style.setProperty('--progress3', value);
  radialProgress3.innerHTML = value;
  radialProgress3.setAttribute('aria-valuenow3', value);
};
setProgress(controller.value);
controller.oninput = () => {
  setProgress(controller.value);
};
setProgress2(controller2.value);
controller2.oninput = () => {
  setProgress2(controller2.value);
};
setProgress3(controller3.value);
controller3.oninput = () => {
  setProgress3(controller3.value);
};
```

```html
<input type="range" value="90" min="0" max="100" class="range">
<div class="RadialProgress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
<input type="range" value="90" min="0" max="100" class="range2">
<div class="RadialProgress2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow2="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
<input type="range" value="90" min="0" max="100" class="range3">
<div class="RadialProgress3" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow3="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вопрос именно про JS часть, имею ввиду что сколько в вёрстке элементов будет вы условно не знаете, тогда можно так:

```js
const controllers = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=range]');
const radialProgresses = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=RadialProgress]');

const setProgress = (progress, index) => {
  const value = `${progress}%`;
  const postfix = index ? index : '';
  controllers[index].style.setProperty(`--progress${postfix}`, value);
  radialProgresses[index].innerHTML = value;
  radialProgresses[index].setAttribute(`aria-valuenow${postfix}`, value);
}

controllers.forEach((controller, index) => {
  setProgress(controller.value, index);

  controller.oninput = () => {
    setProgress(controller.value, index);
  };
})
```

```html
<input type="range" value="90" min="0" max="100" class="range">
<div class="RadialProgress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
<input type="range" value="90" min="0" max="100" class="range1">
<div class="RadialProgress1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow1="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
<input type="range" value="90" min="0" max="100" class="range2">
<div class="RadialProgress2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow2="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, все работает. Если не трудно расскажи что в этом коде делается  const setProgress = (progress, index) => {
  const value = `${progress}%`;
  const postfix = index ? index : '';

Comment: Я пытался с циклом тут замутить, все оказывается без него решается

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста ${progress} и ${postfix} что это?

Comment: @АлексейПетров Цикл есть - `forEach`. На счёт вашего вопроса: `${progress}` - это я взял из вашего кода, думал вы знаете что пишите)) На счёт `index ? index : ''` - это работает так, что 0 в JS может быть представлен как `false`, следовательно для первого элемента не будет никакого индекса, но любое другое число может быть представлено как `true`, потому для них вернётся их же значение. Т.е. для 0 вернётся пустая строка, а для всех других само же число, для 1 вернётся 1, для 2 - 2 и т.д.

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, пожалуйста, примите его, поставив зелёную галочку слева от моего ответа

Comment: Нет  код не мой поэтому и спросил что это за конструкция ${progress}, вот это ${postfix} уже ваше.

Comment: @АлексейПетров Это позволяет преврщать (в данном случае) числа в строку нужного вида. Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать функцию - например `inputBlock(7)`, и в нее передавать количество блоков, которые нужно создать, пример ниже.

```js
const out = document.querySelector('.out')

inputBlock(7)

function inputBlock(number) {

  let wrapper
  let input
  let divRange

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    wrapper = document.createElement('div')
    input = document.createElement('input')
    divRange = document.createElement('div')


    input.type = 'range';
    input.classList.add('range');
    input.setAttribute('min', 0);
    input.setAttribute('max', 100);
    input.setAttribute('value', 90);

    divRange.classList.add('RadialProgress');
    divRange.setAttribute('role', 'progressbar');
    divRange.textContent = `${input.value}%`;


    wrapper.append(input)
    wrapper.append(divRange)
    out.append(wrapper)
  }

  inputClick()

}

function inputClick() {
  out.addEventListener('input', function({
    target
  }) {
    if (target.classList.contains('range')) {
      target.nextSibling.textContent = `${target.value}%`
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="out"></div>
```

**P.S вариант цвет для [type="range"]**

Примерно так, но я понял, что ответ другого участника вас устроил. Поэтому это для наглядности

```js
const out = document.querySelector('.out')

inputBlock(3)

function inputBlock(number) {

  let wrapper
  let input
  let divRange

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    wrapper = document.createElement('div')
    input = document.createElement('input')
    divRange = document.createElement('div')


    input.type = 'range';
    input.classList.add('range');
    input.classList.add('slider-progress');
    input.setAttribute('min', 0);
    input.setAttribute('max', 100);
    input.setAttribute('value', 90);

    divRange.classList.add('RadialProgress');
    divRange.setAttribute('role', 'progressbar');
    divRange.textContent = `${input.value}%`;

    wrapper.append(input)
    wrapper.append(divRange)
    out.append(wrapper)
  }

  const progress = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-progress')

  inputClick()
  inputColor(progress)

}

function inputClick() {
  out.addEventListener('input', function({
    target
  }) {
    if (target.classList.contains('range')) {
      target.nextSibling.textContent = `${target.value}%`
    }
  })
}

function inputColor(progress) {
  for (let e of progress) {
    e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value);
    e.style.setProperty('--min', e.min == '' ? '0' : e.min);
    e.style.setProperty('--max', e.max == '' ? '100' : e.max);
    e.addEventListener('input', () => e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value));
  }
}
```

```css
.range {
  width: 100%;
}


/*generated with Input range slider CSS style generator (version 20211225)
https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler*/

input[type=range].range {
  height: 1em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/*progress support*/

input[type=range].range.slider-progress {
  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / var(--range));
  --sx: calc(0.5 * 1.5em + var(--ratio) * (100% - 1.5em));
}

input[type=range].range:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/*webkit*/

input[type=range].range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007CF8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: calc(max((0.4em - 1px - 1px) * 0.5, 0px) - 1.5em * 0.5);
}

input[type=range].range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].range:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].range:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].range.slider-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8612D5, #E510C0) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #EFEFEF;
}


/*mozilla*/

input[type=range].range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007CF8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}

input[type=range].range::-moz-range-track {
  height: max(calc(0.4em - 1px - 1px), 0px);
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].range:hover::-moz-range-track {
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].range:active::-moz-range-track {
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].range.slider-progress::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8612D5, #E510C0) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #EFEFEF;
}


/*ms*/

input[type=range].range::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].range::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].range::-ms-thumb {
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007CF8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].range::-ms-track {
  height: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].range.slider-progress::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: max(calc(0.4em - 1px - 1px), 0px);
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  margin: -1px 0 -1px -1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8612D5, #E510C0);
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  border-right-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="out"></div>
```

Comment: Тут еще в CSS файле цвет полосы меняется .range {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      left,
      $red 0%,
      $red var(--progress, 90%),
      #bcbcbe var(--progress, 90%),
      #bcbcbe 100%
   );
}  как прикрутить эту функцию к изменению var(--progress, 90%)

Comment: @АлексейПетров добавил цвет для наглядности. Если ответ полезный - кликните стрелку вверх, слева от моего ответа

Comment: @АлександрСычёв Он не может пока что голосовать за, нужно минимум 15 репутации :)

Comment: @Mr.Man точно )) переживу ))